# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using larger boost-matrices

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault

If I run the code the error occurs:  **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

The problem does not exist if I decrease the dimensions of MatSamplesDimM in the header-file (e.g. from 300000 to 30000) or if I just declare Matrix1 and not Matrix2 in the main-file. The problem is independent of environment in which I run the code (eclipse or from terminal).

Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

StrangeBehavior.cpp is my main-File:

```
// System includes
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>   //fstream: Stream class to both read and write from/to files; for output

// Boost includes
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp>      //to create normal distribution
#include <vector>                                   // stl vector header
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>  //accumulator for mean, variance...
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector_proxy.hpp>     // for using row()...
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>     // for using row()...
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector_expression.hpp>   // for using inner_prod
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_expression.hpp>   // for using inner_prod, element_div
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp> // for Gamma function

#include "ParameterDeclaration.hpp"

using namespace std; // saves us typing std:: before vector


int main() {

    std::cout << "Starting " << std::endl;

          MatSamplesDimM    Matrix1;
          MatSamplesDimM    Matrix2;

    std::cout << "Finishing" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and ParameterDeclaration.hpp my header-File:

```
#ifndef parameter_
#define parameter_


#include <iostream>

namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;

typedef     ublas::bounded_matrix<double,300000,2>        MatSamplesDimM;


#endif
```

Comment: Possible stack overflow - I don't know anything about this boost lib, but it seems like it's trying to create an array on the stack. Just a wild guess.

Comment: But what can I do? The memory of a matrix 300000*2*4bits which is not that large.

Comment: No idea, never used this. You're right, that it's not that large, BUT for the heap (a typical stack is about 1MB for example). One thing that comes to my mind - try to allocate this object dynamically. I mean like `MatSamplesDimM* Matrix1 = new MatSamplesDimM;` It may be disallowed by the lib, but worth the shot.

Comment: @user1669205 Where did you get "4 bits" from?  To me it looks like 300,000 * 2 * 8 bytes, which is 4,800,000 - way too large for even a generous stack...  And you've got two of them!  Heap allocation will get around this.

Comment: @paddy You are right with the bytes. On the first try is works with the dynamical allocation! Thanks for hint. I dont know much about heap and stack and I have to look into that which I do now. I will try that for the whole code and see if it works!

Comment: The general idea is this: the stack is the temporary storage where the variables used in your functions live.  As you make nested function calls, the stack usage grows.  The stack is designed so you can make quite a lot of nested calls with quite a lot of data, but not stupid amounts of data.  If you have anything significant to store, you should use the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the heap instead of the stack. This means allocate the matrices using **new**.